# Hive - select data from group with at least one row containing

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Suppose i have a table in hive like so:

```
|Id|Data |Data2 |Groupkey|
|1 |One  |      |Group1  |
|2 |Two  |Stuff |Group1  |
|3 |Shoes|Some  |Group2  |
|4 |four |Stuff |Group2  |
|5 |Three|Notme |Group3  |
```

For each group  that contains 'Stuff' in `Data2` i want to get the row that has `Groupkey` and `Data` from the row other than the `Stuff`, and `Data2` from 'Stuff' row.

So resulting data set would look something like

```
|Group |Data |Data2|
|Group1|One  |Two  |
|Group2|Shoes|four |
```

I was hoping to get something going with a `GROUP BY`, i started going with

`SELECT Data, Groupkey FROM (SELECT Data, GroupKey FROM MyTable GROUP BY Groupkey) WHERE Data2 <> 'Stuff'` but this fails suggesting i need to include Data in the group by but that is not what i want to group by?

And i'm not sure how to select just the groups containing one row with certain data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select      Groupkey                                            as `Group`
           ,min (case when Data2 <> 'Stuff' then Data end)      as Data
           ,min (case when Data2 =  'Stuff' then Data end)      as Data2

from        MyTable

group by    Groupkey

having      count (case when Data2 = 'Stuff' then 1 end) > 0
;
```

---

```
+--------+-------+-------+
| group  | data  | data2 |
+--------+-------+-------+
| Group1 | One   | Two   |
| Group2 | Shoes | four  |
+--------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT Groupkey, t1.Data, t2.Data as Data2 
FROM t t1
INNER JOIN t t2
ON t1.Groupkey = t2.Groupkey
AND t1.Data2 <> t2.Data2
WHERE t2.Data2 = 'Stuff'
```